# Allow UI updates iOS

Tags: ios, uikit

Let's say I do something like this:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
[self methodThatTakesLotsOfTime];
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

This will won't allow enough time for the HUD to animate in and show. Using `sleep(100)` or an NSTimer will only add to the issue. I can't run the method on the main queue either. Not to mention `dispatch_get_current_queue()` is deprecated for iOS 6.0+. I must be missing something big

Comment: What's the problem? Is it that you want to *prevent* the user from interacting during this? Or is that you don't want to start the `method` until after the animation finishes? Or what?

Comment: I want the method to run after the HUD is open (ie done animating)

Comment: Okay, so the problem here we don't know what this MBProgressHUD is. It is up to them to give you a way to wait until the animation is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a transaction completion handler:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^{
     [self methodThatTakesLotsOfTime];
}];
```

But really that's just a stopgap. It is up to the authors of the code you are using to give you a way to animate with a completion block.